# Django search list in a list with foreign key

Tags: python, django

i'm beginning in django (and coding too) and i can't do something which i guess is super easy . I want to create a simple project management .

I created 2 models : Project and Step . And in step there are  a foreign key for 1 project.

```
class Project(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    project= models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I succed to create a step in a project , to do a list to see all step for 1 project but now  in my home page , i want to list all projects and 4 steps in each project for example :

Project 1 (Step 1, Step 2, Step 3 ,Step 4) 
Project 2 (Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4)

I'm using the ListView , but i don't know what to do , because it's in my step there are the id of project . So how I sort steps by project ?

```
class ProjectList(ListView):
model = Project 
template_name ='project/index.html'
```

Do i need to create a queryset if so what i should write ?

```
queryset = setp.objects.filter(project_id='?')
```

I'm thinking maybe i did something wrong with the foreign key , and i maybe should put task in project .

I hope you understand what i want to do and thank you to read me :)

Comment: do you want to list all the step in each project on the template ? you can use django built in [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/) such as `for` to output the foreign key data

Comment: May I kindly suggest you do the full tutorial ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
   <h1>{{ obj.title }}</h1>
   {% for step in obj.step_set.all %}
      <p>{{ step.title }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

you can do this way in your templates.

Comment: Thank you it's work . Just now when i do the details link is tell me Project matching query does not exist.

Comment: sorry I was not available, if you didn't solve it, pl let me know